# Adding a column to an existing table with values

Tags: ktor, kotlin-exposed

I currently have a TABLE object, as below and existing table in DB. I am creating a webservice using KTOR.

```
object Arts: Table() {
    val id : Column<Int> = integer("id").autoIncrement().primaryKey()
    val title = varchar("title" , 256)
    val description = varchar("desc", 512)
    val price = double("price")
}
```

I would like to add a column, last_modified how to alter the current table.

Answer (score 4):

First, add the column last_modified to your table.

```kotlin
object Arts: Table() {
    val id : Column<Int> = integer("id").autoIncrement().primaryKey()
    val title = varchar("title" , 256)
    val description = varchar("desc", 512)
    val price = double("price")
    val lastModified = datetime("last_modified").defaultExpression(CurrentDateTime())
}
```

Then call the function

```kotlin
SchemaUtils.createMissingTablesAndColumns(Arts)
```